# If $L_1.L_2$ is regular, and $L_1$ is regular, then $L_2$ is regular?

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions, finite-automata

A regular language (also called a rational language) is a formal language that can be expressed using a regular expression.

> Assume that $L=L_1.L_2$ is a regular language. Also assume that $L_1$ is regular. Is it true that $L_2$ is regular too ?

Note: Please prove it using a DFA. I know how to do that with regular expressions. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The empty language $\emptyset$ is regular and for every language $L$, $\emptyset L = \emptyset$ is also regular. This does not imply that $L$ is regular.

**Edit**. To answer your comment, here is another counterexample. Let $A$ be the alphabet. Then, for every language $L$ containing the empty word, $A^*L = A^*$. This does not imply that $L$ is regular.

Comment: Assume that $L_1$ is not empty. then what ?

Comment: Also, i don't get it ... why is $\lambda.L=\lambda $?? i thought it should be equal to $L$!!!

Comment: What does denote $\lambda$ for you? You seem to confuse the empty language and the language reduced to the empty word.